# Improper integral at unbound domain

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, jacobian

I'm trying to calculate the improper integral $$\int\int_D\frac{1}{x^4+y^2}dxdy$$ where the domain is : $$D = ((x,y)|x\ge1,y\ge{x^2}) $$
I'm struck at figuring out how to change the parameters adequately, and determining the new domain. Any ideas?

Comment: change the order of integration to $dy dx$

Comment: If you mean: $1\le{y}\le\sqrt{x}$ and $1\le{x}\le{n}$, then it leads to a very difficult integral.

Comment: $x^2\leq  y <\infty  , 1\leq x < \infty $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\dfrac{y}{x^2}=u$ and $x=v$ then $1\leq u<\infty$ and $1\leq v<\infty$, also $|J|=-v^2$, we find
$$\int\int_D\frac{1}{x^4+y^2}dxdy=\int_1^\infty\int_1^\infty\frac{1}{1+u^2}\frac{-1}{v^2}dudv=\color{blue}{\dfrac{\pi}{4}}$$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: You may use a change of coordinates $(x,y)=(x,x^2 t)$ after which the integral separates and is easily calculated (if I didn't make a mistake)

Comment: can you elaborate on that please?

Comment: Well it's just what MyGlasses carried out in details (except he uses the letter $u$ instead of $t$ and that he has a sign error which is, however, easily corrected).